# How to maximize (baking) surface area?

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry

I like eating crust, so I am trying different baking molds to try to get the most crust per dough.

More generally, I'm interested in the *reverse* of this more [specific question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179689/maximizing-volume-of-a-rectangular-solid-given-surface-area) — **how to maximize the surface area of a body given a constant volume**. Let's ignore all the practicalities and make it a pure mathematical problem. I'm not a mathematician, so I don't even know how to try to solve it. Intuitively I came up with the following body, but I have no way of verifying its optimality: imagine a sea urchin with infinitely many infinitesimal spikes that are not touching, all anchored to an infinitesimal blob in the center. It is less and less dense as you progress from the center, so some branching could improve it.

So, what is the optimal body, given no other constraints? Please exclude Gabriel's Horn if possible; no infinite dimensions unless they fit into an oven, I mean, a finite space.

Comment: A very long pipe can be made fit in a finite oven...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no well defined answer.

A very long pipe has area going to infinity yet can have a finite volume.

For example, suppose you want $V=\pi$. The volume is $V(r,h)=\pi r^2 h$. Consider a sequence of pipes of dimension $\displaystyle r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $h=n$.

Now the area is $A(r,h)=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh\sim 2\pi\sqrt{n}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 6):

With the idea of the sea urchin you are on the right track. Basically, you are on the way to create a [fractal surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal).

Here are some pictures of simple fractal surfaces (constructed similar to [Koch's snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) in 2d) taken from the Wikipedia site:
[image]
[image]

You get infinite surface but finite volume and finite perimeter.