# Revolution of fractal

Tags: surfaces, fractals, mathematica

How to find the volume and surface area of a shape which made from revolution of [Koch Snowflake](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KochSnowflake.html)?

(I think the surface area will be an infinity, because length of the Koch snowflake is infinity.)

And how to plot it in *Mathematica?*

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Comment: @par That's the area enclosed by the snowflake, not the surface area of the rotated version.

Comment: @par Therefore volume will be finite

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate its centroid and utilise [Pappuss Centroid theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html).

Comment: This is not easy to find the geometric centroid of fractal

Comment: @vito Try calculating the centroid of each iteration and find its limit.

Comment: This is to compute the surface area. As long as the centroid is not in the axis of revolution then it will travel a non-zero distance. Since the arc-length of the fractal is infinite, the surface area will be infinite. You can prove that the centroid is not in the axis using the 'center of mass' definition.

Answer (score 0):

Please, find an implementation in Wolfram Mathematica, for example [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FunWithKochSnowflakes/).
To obtatin square Koch's snowflake area at least in 2D, you could check [this](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/ksnow/area.htm), for sure. If fact, I didn't get about a law of surface revolution of Koch snowflake in your case. Are you talking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610393/how-to-maximize-baking-surface-area) case of generalization in 3D, aren't you? If so, you could estimate the volume by counting volumes of pyramidas to be involved in such a solid and you could estimate the surface area by counting the squares of triangles as well.